# the Operation has Time out Error in Docker

Tags: docker

I install the Docker 3.5.2 which is letest version of Docker and after Installation i open the Docker Desktop It will show Pop up message the Operation has time out.

Download From the Follwing Link :

https://hub.docker.com/editions/community/docker-ce-desktop-windows

[image]

the log file is show as below:

```
 Version: 3.5.2 (66501)
Sha1: 84e4b4334c1e4ea66e074cf2d17440e1f62ab201
Started on: 2021/07/20 15:35:25.714
Resources: C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources
OS: Windows 10 Pro
Edition: Professional
Id: 2009
Build: 19043
BuildLabName: 19041.1.amd64fre.vb_release.191206-1406
File: C:\Users\SPE19\AppData\Local\Docker\log.txt
CommandLine: "C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Docker Desktop.exe" 
You can send feedback, including this log file, at https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues
[15:35:25.799][GUI               ][Info   ] Starting...
[15:35:25.940][GUI               ][Info   ] An instance is already running. Launching the container view.
[15:35:25.987][GUI               ][Error  ] System.TimeoutException:
The operation has timed out.
   at System.IO.Pipes.NamedPipeClientStream.ConnectInternal(Int32 timeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Int32 startTime)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at HttpOverStream.NamedPipe.NamedPipeDialer.<DialAsync>d__8.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at HttpOverStream.Client.DialMessageHandler.<SendAsync>d__9.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.<FinishSendAsyncBuffered>d__58.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Docker.Program.Run(IReadOnlyCollection`1 args) in C:\workspaces\PR-16070\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Desktop\Program.cs:line 196
[15:37:14.984][GUI               ][Error  ] System.ArgumentException:
Unable to create an instance of Docker.App: Unable to create an instance of Docker.ApiServices.Update.UpdateCheckTimer: Unable to create an instance of Docker.ApiServices.Update.Updater: Unable to create an instance of Docker.Notifications.BackgroundUpdateWatcher: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
   at Docker.Core.Di.Singletons.NewInstance(Type type, Int32 depth) in C:\workspaces\PR-16070\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Core\di\Singletons.cs:line 89
   at Docker.Core.Di.Singletons.Get(Type type, Int32 depth) in C:\workspaces\PR-16070\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Core\di\Singletons.cs:line 51
   at Docker.Core.Di.Singletons.Get[T]() in C:\workspaces\PR-16070\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Core\di\Singletons.cs:line 28
   at Docker.Program.Run(IReadOnlyCollection`1 args) in C:\workspaces\PR-16070\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Desktop\Program.cs:line 268

  System.ArgumentException:
  Unable to create an instance of Docker.ApiServices.Update.UpdateCheckTimer: Unable to create an instance of Docker.ApiServices.Update.Updater: Unable to create an instance of Docker.Notifications.BackgroundUpdateWatcher: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
     at Docker.Core.Di.Singletons.NewInstance(Type type, Int32 depth) in C:\workspaces\PR-16070\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Core\di\Singletons.cs:line 89
     at Docker.Core.Di.Singletons.Get(Type type, Int32 depth) in C:\workspaces\PR-16070\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Core\di\Singletons.cs:line 51
     at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext()
     at System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)
     at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
     at Docker.Core.Di.Singletons.NewInstance(Type type, Int32 depth) in C:\workspaces\PR-16070\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Core\di\Singletons.cs:line 83
  
     System.ArgumentException:
     Unable to create an instance of Docker.ApiServices.Update.Updater: Unable to create an instance of Docker.Notifications.BackgroundUpdateWatcher: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
        at Docker.Core.Di.Singletons.NewInstance(Type type, Int32 depth) in C:\workspaces\PR-16070\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Core\di\Singletons.cs:line 89
        at Docker.Core.Di.Singletons.Get(Type type, Int32 depth) in C:\workspaces\PR-16070\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Core\di\Singletons.cs:line 51
        at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext()
        at System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)
        at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
        at Docker.Core.Di.Singletons.NewInstance(Type type, Int32 depth) in C:\workspaces\PR-16070\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Core\di\Singletons.cs:line 83
     
         System.ArgumentException:
         Unable to create an instance of Docker.Notifications.BackgroundUpdateWatcher: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
            at Docker.Core.Di.Singletons.NewInstance(Type type, Int32 depth) in C:\workspaces\PR-16070\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Core\di\Singletons.cs:line 93
            at Docker.Core.Di.Singletons.Get(Type type, Int32 depth) in C:\workspaces\PR-16070\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Core\di\Singletons.cs:line 51
            at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext()
            at System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)
            at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
            at Docker.Core.Di.Singletons.NewInstance(Type type, Int32 depth) in C:\workspaces\PR-16070\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Core\di\Singletons.cs:line 83
         
              System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException:
              Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
                 at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
                 at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
                 at Docker.Core.Di.Singletons.NewInstance(Type type, Int32 depth) in C:\workspaces\PR-16070\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Core\di\Singletons.cs:line 83
              
                    System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException:
                    Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {1ECCA34C-E88A-44E3-8D6A-8921BDE9E452} failed due to the following error: 80080005 Server execution failed (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80080005 (CO_E_SERVER_EXEC_FAILURE)).
                       at Docker.Notifications.BackgroundUpdateWatcher..ctor(ISystrayNotifications systray, IUpdateStateNotifier updateStateNotifier) in C:\workspaces\PR-16070\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Desktop\Notifications\BackgroundUpdateWatcher.cs:line 12
```

I also enable hyper-v .

thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same error.

but i fixed it by uninstalling docker and reinstalling it, but this time i deselect the "Install windows dependencies for WSL 2".

and make sure you delete the docker files from the previous intallation before re-installing